# I am not able to run test cases in Edge Chromium Browser in selenium robot frame work. Could you pls help me

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, robotframework

I am not able to run test cases in Edge Chromium Browser in robot frame work. Could you pls help me.

Browser is opening but not calling my application.Not even calling **google.com** in edge chromium.

```
*** Settings ***

Library     SeleniumLibrary


*** Variables ***

${browser}      chrome
${url}          https://www.google.com/

*** Test Cases ***

LoginTest

        open browser        ${url}     ${browser}
        Maximize browser window
```

Here are messages from the log:

```
12:00:22.429    INFO    Opening browser 'edge' to base url 'https://www.google.com/'.   
12:00:22.430    WARN    This version of Selenium does not support options argument. 
12:00:24.226    FAIL    WebDriverException: Message: Unknown error
```

Note:Same test case working in chrome and firefox

Comment: Please add steps or code you are using

Comment: Judging by the error, you have an older version of chromedriver. What version of chrome and chromedriver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

- You should update your selenium version. Your selenium version does not support it .
- Try to install Selenium2Library and try it again.
- Open cmd and execute this
- **pip install robotframework-selenium2library**
- **pip install --upgrade robotframework-selenium2library**
- Change your library **Selenium2Library** on the scripts. like this.